# How to reduce Pycharm memory usage?

Tags: python, pycharm

Recently I got working to something that needs a lot of memory while using Pycharm. How should I possibly reduce the memory to about 550MB? My current is 1198MB. (I'm using **Windows 10**, **Pycharm Community Edition 2022.2.4**)

Comment: Don't use PyCharm.

Comment: you can try messing around with disabling indexing, but then, why would you want to use PyCharm? That's sort of the main reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the heap size.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html

Answer (score 0):

Use vscode with the python extensions. I switched over a while back because of the same issue. The memory footprint and cpu usage is a fraction of what pycharm uses.

You can also easily manage and choose conda environments, it even has jupyter notebook extensions made by Microsoft with great compatibility.

I use it both on my Mac and windows systems.